# Kendo Panelbar - Adding a checkbox to panels to select multiple panel header

Tags: javascript, checkbox, kendo-ui, panelbar

What I want to achieve is to add checkboxes to the panel headers in a `PanelBar` like in the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nX8r/31/) which I have created.

Below is the html:

```
<ul id='panelbar'>
    <li class='k-state-active'> <span class='k-link k-state-selected'>Tab 1 <input type="checkbox" class="cbSelect"/></span>
        <div>Test 1</div>
    </li>
    <li> <span class='k-link k-state-selected'> Tab2 <input type="checkbox" class="cbSelect"/></span>
        <div>Test 2</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've found that when you try to check the checkbox, that tab opens.

**Is it possible to disable the onclick method for the clicked tab when clicking on the checkbox?**

*and if so, any ideas on how I can achieve this?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just prevent the propagation :

```
$("#panelbar").on("click", "input.cbSelect", function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
})
```

See : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nX8r/33/).